# BigQuery Error while trying to query data?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to run simple query on Google Bigquery. But each time when I run the query `SELECT COUNT(totals.visits) FROM 122443995.ga_sessions_20160817` I get following error

`Encountered " "FROM" "FROM "" at line 1, column 29. Was expecting: <EOF>`

What could be the possible error in the query syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to escape the table name. With [legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#from), you would use square brackets, e.g.:

```
SELECT COUNT(totals.visits) FROM [122443995.ga_sessions_20160817];
```

With [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/), you would use backticks, e.g.:

```
SELECT COUNT(totals.visits) FROM `122443995.ga_sessions_20160817`;
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, using parentheses to surround the clause in FROM solved it for me.
So instead of

```
SELECT totals FROM t1
```

use

```
SELECT totals FROM (t1)
```